# How to set extension attribute to Order search interface api magento 2

Tags: magento2.2.6, magento2-api

Please review following files:

> OrderRepositoryPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace Retailinsights\Cartrules\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory as ProductRepository;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderSearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory as ProductImageHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * Class OrderRepositoryPlugin
 */
class OrderRepositoryPlugin {
    /**
     *@var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
     */
    protected $productImageHelper;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepository
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * Order Comment field name
     */
    const FIELD_NAME = 'unitm';

    /**
     * Order Extension Attributes Factory
     *
     * @var OrderExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $extensionFactory;

    /**
     * OrderRepositoryPlugin constructor
     *
     * @param OrderExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
     */

    public function __construct(
        ProductImageHelper $productImageHelper,
        OrderExtensionFactory $extensionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productImageHelper = $productImageHelper;
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function afterGet(OrderRepositoryInterface $subject, OrderInterface $order) {
        $addAtt = array();
        $info = array();   
        $addImage = array();
        $infoImage = array(); 

        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItems) {
            $itemExtAttr = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
            $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($orderItems->getProductId());
            $uom = $product->getUnitm();
            $weight = round($product->getWeight(), 0);
            $optionId = $product->getUnitm();
            $attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('unitm');
            if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
                $optionText = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($optionId);
            }

            $sku = $orderItems->getSku();

            $imageurl =$this->productImageHelper->create()->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->setImageFile($product->getThumbnail())->getUrl();
            $addAtt[$sku] = $weight." ".$optionText;
            $addImage[$sku] = $imageurl;
        } 

        $info[] = $addAtt; 
        $infoImage[] = $addImage;
        $data = json_encode($info);
        $dataImage = json_encode($infoImage);
        $orderComment = $order->getData(self::FIELD_NAME);

        $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->extensionFactory->create();
        $extensionAttributes->setUnitm($data);
        $extensionAttributes->setImageUrl($dataImage);
        $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        return $order;
    }
}
```

> extension_attributes.xml

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
    <attribute code="image_url" type="string" />
    <attribute code="unitm" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
```

Here I am trying to set extension attribute to order interface, but its working in other Orders but not in search criteria, how to achieve it, Thank you in advance.
API is like `rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_email&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=me345@gmail.com`

Comment: did you found the solution?